Should I run a moderated regression or a regression on a subset of my data?
My hypothesis is that my iv predicts my dv only among people who have a PhD.
I have seen two ways to test this hypothesis:

Run a regression with a moderation between my iv and the education variable
Run a regression using only the subset of people in my sample who have a PhD

Can you help me understand the statistical and methodological pros and cons of each of these methods?
Best regards,
The following is an r code in order to have a reproducible example.
set.seed(123)
n <- 2000

education_levels <- c("High School", "Bachelor", "Master", "PhD")
education <- factor(sample(education_levels, n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.25, 0.35, 0.25, 0.15)),
                    levels = education_levels)

iv <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

dv <- rnbinom(n, mu = 10, size = 0.5)

df <- data.frame(
  education_level = education,
  iv = iv,
  dv = dv
)

# Regressions
library(MASS)
library(gtsummary)

moderated_reg <- glm.nb(dv ~ iv * education_level, 
                        df) %>%
  tbl_regression()

subset_reg <- glm.nb(dv ~ iv,
                     subset(df, education_level == "PhD")) %>%
  tbl_regression()

tbl_merge(
  tbls = list(moderated_reg, subset_reg),
  tab_spanner = c("**Moderated regression**", "**Subset regression**")
  )


First, just running a model only for those who have a PhD won't answer your question, because it gives you no information about whether your iv predicts the DV among people who do not. Second, it doesn't really work to have a hypotheses that something does not have an effect, or that the effect is zero. This is because most statistical tests are concerned with whether or not something is significantly different from zero. If the test is not significant that's not evidence that the effect is zero, but just that we don't have enough evidence to say that it is not zero. So I think a better way to phrase your hypothesis is that you think the effect of the IV is significantly larger for people with PhDs, compared to those without PhDs.
If that is true, then the approach you want is the second one: run a model for the entire population with an interaction term (what you call a "moderation") between PhD and the IV.
The interaction term explicitly tests whether the effect of the IV is significantly different for people with PhDs (vs for those without). This is closer to an explicit test of your hypothesis, that the nature of the effect significantly differs based on whether you have a PhD. If you make "no PhD" the reference category then the interpretation of the three coefficients will be

PhD: The effect of having a PHD on the DV when the IV is zero
iv: The effect of the IV for people without a PHD
interaction term: how the effect of the IV differs for those with a PHD, compared to those without.

(note that if "zero" is not a meaningful value for your interaction term, you want to mean center it or something, so that the interpretations above make sense)
Your hypothesis would predict that the interaction term is positive. You also seem to think that the main effect of the IV (which in a model with an interaction term tells you the effect for people without a PhD) should be "close to zero" but because the significance of that coefficient depends on your sample size, it doesn't really make sense to make a prediction that it is not significant.

Many thanks!
Surprisingly, the iv coefficient was highly significant when using only the subset of Ph.D. respondents. It is almost no longer significant when using an interaction term between the iv and level of education.
If I understand that using the subset is not the right way to test my hypothesis, can you tell what is going on?
Is it because the interaction term tests PhD * iv against no PhD * iv to predict the dv, while the subset only tests a regression with the dv ?

In the phd alone model, the iv coefficient tells you if the effect is significantly different from zero among the phd group. In the interaction model the main iv coefficient tells you if the effect is significantly different from zero among non-phDs, and the interaction term tells you if the effect  for PhDs is significantly different from the effect for non PhDs.
